# Fixing detached head on a renamed git branch

Tags: git, github

New to git here. I have a feature branch (`feature/123`) that was originally cut from `develop`, worked on, and then pushed to GitHub.

I just started making some local changes to this branch and then I decided I wanted to preserve my changes (not throw them away entirely) and start over fresh with the version of the branch that is currently up on GitHub.

So I decided to:

1. Commit my changes (that I want to preserve and *possibly* -- though not likely -- come back to)
2. Rename my feature branch
3. Pull the `feature/123` branch thats on the origin (GitHub)

So I:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Saving changes made thus far"
git branch -m feature/123-OLD
git checkout origin/feature/123
```

When I did this I saw:

```
$ git checkout origin/feature/123
Note: checking out 'origin/feature/123'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 8877c28... 123: did some stuff
```

And *now* when I look at my current branch, I see:

```
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at origin/feature/123)
```

develop

All this "detached head" stuff is creepin me out!

All I want is to have a local branch named `feature/123` that is at the same exact state that GitHub is at. **How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: so you want to create new branch base on commit?

Comment: Thanks @Feri (+1) although this is probably better suited as a comment. I currently renamed my local `feature/123` branch to `feature/123-OLD`. I now want a *new* local feature branch called `feature/123` that is the exact same as GitHub's `feature/123` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three commands here were all good:

> > ```
> > git add .
> > git commit -m "Saving changes made thus far"
> > git branch -m feature/123-OLD
> > ```

The last one changed the name `feature/123` to the name `feature/123-OLD` (assuming, of course, that you were on a branch named `feature/123` in the first place).

The last command is not *wrong*, it's just not the one you wanted:

> > ```
> > git checkout origin/feature/123
> > ```

What you wanted was:

```
git checkout feature/123
```

This would look around at your (local) branch names, *not* find anything named `feature/123` (it doesn't exist any more—`feature/123-OLD` exists but that's not the same), and then invoke the "do what I mean" feature of `git checkout`.

This feature says: *Hmm, I can't find the branch you asked for.  I think maybe you meant for me to create a **new** branch!  Can I find exactly one remote-tracking name, like `origin/feature/123`, that looks a lot like `feature/123`?  If I can find none, or two or more, I'll complain and fail.  But if I can find **exactly one**, I'll make a **new** `feature/123`, pointing to the same commit as the remote-tracking name!*

And of course, it will find just one, so it will create `feature/123`.  When it *does* create `feature/123`, it will default to setting its upstream to `origin/feature/123`.  That's the *Do What I Mean* or DWIM mode of `checkout` and it is in fact what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could just checkout the required branch

```
git checkout feature/123
```